# make auto increment in postges using composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which stores user's records. I need this table to make a unique id for a record of the user which created this record (whereas in the entire table IDs may be repeated).
For example:

| record_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

So each user can have only one record with a specific id.

At this moment my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "notes" (
  "id" int,
  "user" int,
  "text" varchar,
  "created" timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON "notes" ("id", "user");
```

I want my database to increment IDs of each record automatically (and make this id unique for the user created it) when a user inserts something.

Is there any ways to achieve it?

I hope I've explained my question clear enough. If no, please ask me and I will update my question.

**Update:** I tried to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO "notes" VALUES (
    5, 1, 'test1', NULL, ('2023-06-27 13:12:29.611415')::TIMESTAMP
) 
ON CONFLICT (id, "user") DO 
UPDATE SET id = "notes".id + 1;
```

but sometimes it returns an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "notes_id_user_idx"` (because users can delete some of their records). I want my database to generate unique ID until it finds an ID that a user doesn't have.

Also it seems that this request changed the id not of the record I am trying to insert, but of the one with which the conflict occurred. I don't want to change already saved records, I want to generate an id while inserting a record into the table.

Comment: What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: @istepaniuk at this moment I make a record's id in my program. but I want the database to do it. I don't understand enough how to implement it

Comment: Don't do that. Just fill `record_id` from a sequence. If you need an ID per user, generate it on the lly when you `SELECT`.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe yes, this is a good idea, but how to write this sequence? I mean I've read about sequences but I found only 'start with', 'increment', 'max value', 'min value' key words. but how to tell sequence to use a unique constraint and look for a unique id for a specific user?

Comment: You *don't* look for a special user when you create the value. The primary key is only `record_id`. Look for "identity column".

Comment: Use an identity column, generated by default: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: You want to create visible serial numbers for each record of each user. There are multiple solutions for this, but all revolve around controlling concurrency when assigning numbers, You can do that online with the use of a separate table to store and handle the "latest sequence number" for each user (and control locking to it), or you can do it in a deferred way (a process that assigns the numbers after a few minutes).